# is there a counterexample of this map isn't surjective?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, self-learning

[image]
The ring A is a commutative ring with identity.

I think ii) is true if they are not coprime.

because for every (x+a1,....,x+an) we can find a x such that f(x)= (x+a1,....,x+an).

Could you please show me a example that f(x) is not surjective？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $A=\mathbb{Z}$ and $a_1=a_2=2\mathbb{Z}$. Then the map is not surjective. For instance the element $(\overline 1, \overline 0)$ is not in the image.

Comment: what's the mean of ¯1?

Comment: The class of $1$ in the quotient (or $1+a_1$ with your notation).

Comment: How silly I am...